# How to copy files of specific size from one blob container to another blob container?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to copy files of Specific size(like files size greater than or less than 100 mb) from one blob to another blob container or any location using ADF or any other Azure resources which can help achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use `logic app`. The following is the design process:

[image]

[image]

Note that the unit of `size` is bytes, you need to convert it.

Here are the test results:

**Source container**

[image]

**Destination container**

[image]

The test results look okay.